# Avoid if-else block in favor of default assignment followed by if

Tags: javascript, optimization, conditions

A colleague, and frankly better software engineer that me, is telling me that this pattern

```
let variable = someDefaultVariable();
if (some_boolean) {
    variable = someOtherValue();
}
```

is better than this pattern

```
let variable
if (some_boolean) {
    variable = someOtherValue();
} else {
    variable = someDefaultVariable();
}
```

My doubt about this is that the initial instantiation is going to involve a waterfall of function calls before the `if` block is hit, although he seems convinced that the first approach is better.

Speaking specifically about JavaScript, which of these patterns is better and more secure. Is this the same for C?

Comment: Has your colleague given you any reasons _why_ the first approach is better?

Comment: he said that the first assignment will create a pointer.

Comment: Both are horrific. The first assigns the variable then reassigns it, making the code harder to read and understand. The second declares it then waffles on with `if` and `else` to do the assignment. Just use the ternary operator, which simplifies the code and assigns (once) via the declaration.

Comment: @JoeyGough, "*he said that the first assignment will create a pointer*". No, it won't. Even if it did, how is creating a pointer supposed to be better?

Comment: Your coworker might be right about one JavaScript interpreter, but utterly wrong about the next. The ECMAScript standard does not do a deep dive into how memory should be allocated. Furthermore, there is so much runtime optimization in modern JavaScript interpreters that it frankly isn't worth the time micro optimizing something like this. Go for readability and correctness.

Comment: In fact, [ECMA 4](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-417.pdf) literally has 1 occurrence of the word "memory" in the spec. RAM, heap and stack aren't even mentioned in the spec at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is more of a style issue than anything else, and very susceptible to personal opinion.

The second example in the question more clearly shows intent, which increases the readability of the code, however with the first example, there is no way to have the variable become uninitialised by further code changes breaking the code.

You can however sidestep the problem entirely by defining it explicitly with a conditional operator (ternary):

```
let variable = some_boolean ? someDefaultVariable() : someOtherValue();
```

It's less commonly used, but should be in every programmer's toolbox for tasks like this.  It shows both intent, and is 'cleaner' (less boiler-plate, and variable cannot be unassigned) which I suspect is the reason your colleague prefers the first form.

This answer would not be any different for C, which is actually my background, or most any other language, for that matter.

Comment: +1, but you don't need to surround the ternary statement with parenthesis This works well when there is a default and only 1 other value. This breaks down if there are 3 or more possible values.

Comment: The answer would be slightly different for all languages which support unmodifiable variables (e.g. `const` in TypeScript and C++, `final` in Java, `val` in Scala), because it adds another, and perhaps the strongest, argument in favour of the direct initialisation approach. You cannot make a variable `const`/`final`/`val` otherwise.

Comment: If you coding style prohibits `? : `, then you can extract this to a function and use `return`s in an `if`. If your coding style also prohibits multiple `return` statements, then you are pretty much stuffed.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Java's `final` is better understood as “assigned exactly once”, not as “cannot be changed after the declaration”. If OP's second example were Java, the variable could be final and the compiler would ensure that all paths initialize the variable. In most other languages you are right though that something like a ternary would be preferable.

Comment: @amon: I know what you mean, but I consider that feature more as syntactical sugar for complex initialisations that would become too ugly in a simple `?:` expression.

Comment: @Caleth: If you actually have such a coding style, then any attempt to produce good and readable code is very likely doomed anyway.

Comment: @ChristianHackl you haven't had to code to strict misra standards then...  lucky.

Comment: @Baldrickk: MISRA disallows the conditional operator? Interesting. Why?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I meant to explicitly refer to multiple return statements in a function, which MISRA disallows (big pet peve here)  Unfortunately, those I work with also don't like the conditional operator because "it's confusing" (-\_-)  so I've not yet actually run that one past the checker. (and I don't have a copy of the misra rule-book to hand to check) - yes, I'm working at _that_ company.  Apart from that it's pretty good though, so can't complain.

Comment: Ok, correction/update to the above comment - it's not a misra rule, but SonarQube's rule-set disallows the conditional operator -_-

Comment: @Baldrickk: Thanks for the update! As for the multiple-return issue, I suppose MISRA would disallow those to ease code verification. I cannot argue with that because I don't have first-hand experience in sectors where MISRA matters, but I don't think such a rule makes sense outside that narrow context.

Comment: @ChristianHackl welcome to the wonderful world of programming with safety and security in mind, where the standards you have to meet are forced on you.  The most fun thing so far is that we have two static analysis tools, and they don't always agree.  e.g. Sonar will complain if you have a `catch(...){}` statement (must catch specific exception type, non MISRA rule) whereas Klocwork will complain if you _don't_ have one (MISRA doesn't like exceptions, and only accepts them being handled immediately)

Answer (score 4):

With the first approach you have a variable that is initialized to a value the moment it is created. Adding additional lines between the declaration and `if` statement means you have some meaningful information already in the variable.

```
let variable = someDefaultVariable();

// We know `variable` is some sort of default value, so we
// can predict a sensible result
let variable2 = variable + 3;

if (some_boolean) {
    variable = someOtherValue();
}
```

Contrast that with the second example where adding lines of code in between the variable declaration and the first `if` statement ends up working with an uninitialized value:

```
let variable;

// Here `variable` is undefined, so we get a NaN result at
// run time, but while your coworkers are reading this code
// they might think it will result in a number.
let variable2 = variable + 3;

if (some_boolean) {
    variable = someOtherValue();
} else {
    variable = someOtherValue();
}
```

Code evolves. Leaving variables uninitialized leaves little potholes in the roadway that is your programming logic. It's all to easy to miss things like this when changing code — especially someone *else's* code.

Go for:

1. Correctness (making sure variables are initialized to something is part of "correctness")
2. Readability and understandability

Since this is JavaScript, do not go for optimizing for memory usage or memory layout.

This sort of thing does not exist in the ECMA Script spec, mostly so JavaScript interpreters can have free reign to optimize as they see fit.

---

As mentioned in another answer and in comments, the ternary operator can make this a one-liner, which you can split into multiple lines for readability:

```
let variable = some_condition
    ? someValue()
    : someOtherValue();
```

This becomes unreadable when the variable has 3 or more possible values upon initialization. In that case you can always put the calculation of the initial value into another function:

```
let variable = calculateValue(some_condition);
```

And then calculateValue gets to deal with the `if` statement:

```
function calculateValue(condition2) {
    if (condition1) {
        return value1;
    }
    else if (condition2) {
        return value2;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly vote against your first example, where the `someDefaultVariable()` value gets used even in cases where the correct one is `someOtherValue()` (because of `some_boolean` being true).

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff: I would prefer a ternary expression, as noted in another answer, or defining a function that returns the proper value so the variable does not remain uninitialized.